# Syntax error on import requests with python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, installation, python-import

I am receiving a SyntaxError: invalid syntax when using Import requests using python 3.7

I have re-installed requests.

Import requests
... 
  File "", line 10
    Import requests
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I did not expect any problem.  Using Automate The Boring Stuff with Python by Al Sweigart page 237

Comment: Specify the OS distro you are using and the command you have used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you're using `Import` with a capital 'I' instead of `import` with a lowercase 'i'.

Comment: Thanks, why didn't I see that?  I have been looking at it for hours - I did not see it!!

Comment: No problem, it happens to the best of us